# Up to what Episode/Chapter of One Piece should i see before playing each of Bandai Namco's PC Games?

Tags: one-piece

on Steam there are [several *One Piece* Games](https://store.steampowered.com/publisher/BANDAINAMCO/list/45279/)

- (2015) Pirate Warriors 3
- (2016) Burning Blood
- (2017) Ultimate World Red
- (2019) World Seeker
- (2020) Pirate Warriors 4

the last i saw the series it "ended" but that was because i was watching the 4Kids version and have been looking to get back into the series, more so when i see these games show up on special.

the appearance of the Straw Hat Crew is unfamiliar to be even in Pirate Warriors 3 and i am seeing a bunch of characters i have not seen in the series myself before (have seen some in passing mention) so i would like to avoid spoilers as much as possible by watching/reading the series before i play any of these games

so i am wondering, Up to what Episode/Chapter of *One Piece* should i see before playing each game?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you can keep off from watching the series as the requirement for the first game itself makes you curious for the following arcs. Yet, here is my answer based on the character list seen on wiki/google of games you've mentioned. All the arcs I've mentioned are till the end(inclusive).

1. Pirate Warriors 3 - Marineford arc.
2. (2016) Burning Blood - Return to Sabaody Arc.
3. (2017) Ultimate World Red - Dressrosa arc (could be an overestimate)
4. (2019) World Seeker - Wholecake Island arc.
5. (2020) Pirate Warriors 4 - Wholecake Island arc.

Comment: would i be correct in assuming that the arcs are also in chronological order?

Comment: Yeah they are in chronological order. And i meant you need to watch till that arc for each game. Even though you almost get intro to characters kind of a bit earlier but i posted that seeing the characters major arc.